Add a managed identity as a user to my AzureDevOps organization - so that it can access AzureDevOps resources
I have a managed identity created in Microsoft Entra. I want to give this identity access to my AzureDevOps resources so that I can call the AzureDevOps API using it.
I have followed this URL: link-devops.
I need to create a workload identity in my AKS cluster so that the pods can access my AzureDevOps resources like repos, pipeline, work items, etc through AzureDevOps API. (I will create federated credentials for the same). But, When I try to add this managed identity as a user to my AzureDevOps organization, it shows an error invalid email address. My Azure organization is connected to the tenant where my identity is created. I have seen the same error earlier in my personal subscription, but at that time, the Azure DevOps organization was not connected to the proper tenant, Once I had connected the proper tenant, I was able to add the identity as a user. This time I am using a corporate tenant. There might be a possibility of not having the proper role assignment in my Azure subscription, But the error message is not providing proper data, the invalid email is the wrong information since the managed identity does not have an email.
Any pointers on resolving this issue will help. What Role should I have if I need to add a managed identity as a user in my Azure DevOps organization (I am the Azure DevOps organization owner)?
link

Hi @jereesh thomas, what's the latest state of your issue? Can you share a screenshot of error message when adding MI?

@Ziyang Liu-MSFT , It is added, I did not have the required privileges , The Entra administrator added it for me

Are you a guest user in your target tenant? Would you please share the required privileges? So that it can help others having the same issue.

The user who helped me to add the identity in AzDevOps  has global admin privilege in Entra

I can reproduce the same error when I try to add a MI by its Object ID.

If you do the same, please add it to Azure DevOps by its Name or Application ID.
Go to your tenant's Enterprise applications page, change Application type to All Applications, search your target MI by its Object ID.

Add it to Azure DevOps by Name or Application ID.


Solution: Users with global admin privilege in Azure Tenant adds the MI to the org.
